# Response Parsed Body in Paw. How to identify the Key-Path in a long url?

Tags: paw-app

I have a Paw related question.

Does anybody know how to extract a value from an encoded URL response field with Paw?  The value is the only part of the encoded URL which starts with a %3D (the URL encoded version of an = sign).

Getting the dynamic values out of JSON, a JSON array, a URL, etc worked great.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use our RegExp Match dynamic value for this: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/RegExMatch

- insert the RegExp Match dynamic value first
- as input for RegExp Match use the Response Parsed Body dynamic value (with the key path to the url-encoded field with the id)
- write the regular expression to extract the id from the field (see example in the screenshot)

[image: regexp match and response parsed body combined]

Answer (score 2):

Excellent point Natalia. Instead of the Regex extension I used the **Substring extension**.  This worked perfectly as the size of the encoded URL never changed.